# Regarding Aptana Studio 3 & Android applications

Tags: android, aptana

Wonder if It's posible to programming on Aptana Studio for Android market?

I saw in the new flash version CS5 it's posible to create a new android project and create a APK package.

does this thing posible in Aptana Studio 3? if so, how? Should I need to download some SDK?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!

Just follow [the instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#downloading) for "**Downloading the ADT Plugin**" for Eclipse and everything should work just fine. After installation is done, you can install the SDKs for different versions of Android and sample projects by going (in Aptana) to **Window > Android SDK Manager** or add custom **Android Virtual Devices** (AVD) by going to **Window > AVD Manager**.

Here's also [a short video](http://screencast.com/t/671l6pqWJ) on how to create a project using the samples and run it in a virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in Aptana Studio 3 per se. However, Aptana was acquired by Appcelerator. They have a product called Titanium Studio, which is built on Aptana Studio 3 but adds the ability to create mobile apps for iOS, Android, etc. (all from one codebase -- JavaScript).
http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-studio/

If you want to code your app for Android in Java, then go with Ionut's approach and the ADT plugin.